# How do I save a jpg from a cairo

Tags: c#, svg, gtk, cairo, librsvg

Below is the code I am using to save a png from a svg file.  That works, but I also need to save it as a jpeg.  Can someone advise me on how to do this?

```
    private void RasterizeSvg(string tempsvg, string rsltPath, int _width, int _height)
    {
        bool callSuccessful = SetDllDirectory(@"C:\ProgramDownloads\librsvg\librsvg-dev_2.32.1-1_win32\bin");
        if (!callSuccessful)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not set DLL directory");
        }
        g_type_init();
        IntPtr error;
        IntPtr rsvghandle = rsvg_handle_new_from_file(tempsvg, out error);
        if (error != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.ReadInt32(error).ToString());
        }
        IntPtr cairosurface = cairo_image_surface_create(cairo_format_t.CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, _width, _height);
        IntPtr cairorenderer = cairo_create(cairosurface);
        bool brslt = rsvg_handle_render_cairo(rsvghandle, cairorenderer);

        //cairo_surface_write_to_png(cairosurface, rsltPath);

        IntPtr pixbuf = IntPtr.Zero;
        cairo_set_source_surface(pixbuf, cairosurface, 0, 0);
        cairo_rectangle(pixbuf, 0, 0, _width, _height);
        cairo_fill(pixbuf);

        callSuccessful = gdk_pixbuf_save(pixbuf, rsltPath, "jpg", out error, __arglist(""));
        if (!callSuccessful)
        {
            throw new Exception(error.ToInt32().ToString());
        }
    }
```

I've changed the order of cairo_set_source, putting cairo_rectangle first, but I'm still getting an access violation

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a null pixbuf pointer to cairo_set_source_surface. You should pass something like this...

IntPtr pixbuf = cairo_create (cairosurface);

also

The third argument to gdk_pixbuf_save should be "jpeg"

maybe you should initialise error too?

Comment: ok, will change but I'm not even getting to that point.  I get an access violation on cairo_set_source_surface.  If I put cairo_rectangle first, it throws av also

Comment: OK, I changed it to this:
 IntPtr pixbuf = cairo_image_surface_create(cairo_format_t.CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, _width, _height);
but cairo_set_source still throws av

Comment: making progress, I changed it to IntrPtr pixbuf = cairo_create(cairosurface);
cairo_set_source_surface(pixbuf, cairosurface, 0, 0);
cairo_fill(pixbuf)
and while I'm not sure I have my image, it did all those steps with no av.
However, when I call gdk_pixbuf_save(pixbuf, rsltPath, "jpeg", out error, __arglist("")) it gets the av,  "Attempted to read or write protected memory."

Comment: I initialized the error pointer to IntPtr.Zero, didn't help, but here is something interesting.  I checked the stack.  The error is thrown at " LibrSvgToImg.ConvertSvgToImg.gdk_pixbuf_save(IntPtr pixbuf, String filename, String type, IntPtr& error)"  So I changed my declaration and the parameters to match, however still getting the error.